# Expressing the difference of uniform norms of two vectors in terms of difference of vectors

Tags: normed-spaces

For two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $d$-dimensionsal Euclidean space, is there a way to write $\|x\|_\infty-\|y\|_\infty$ as a function of some sort of the vector $(x-y)$? I haven't been able to find any resources which give any insight into finding such an expression.

Comment: Note that $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ is given by the max, so $\| x\|_{\infty} = \displaystyle \max_{1\leq i \leq n} |x_{i}| $

Comment: @RyanHowe Yes, that is the definition of the uniform norm. But that doesn't bring you any closer to finding an expression in terms of $(x-y)$.

Comment: True, you can bound it using the reverse triangle inequality though I imagine. $ | \|x\|_{\infty} - \|y\|_{\infty} | \leq \|x \|_{\infty} - \|y \|_{\infty}$

Comment: @RyanHowe Dang, I was hoping there existed a strict equality. Thanks though!

Comment: Oops, I meant $ \|  \|x\|_{\infty} - \|y \|_{\infty} | \leq \| x -y\|_{\infty}$. Yeah, I don't think there is one.